# GetMessage() given an System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dllimport

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern
            bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, int vk);
        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern
            bool GetMessage(ref Message lpMsg, IntPtr handle, uint mMsgFilterInMain, uint mMsgFilterMax);

        public const int MOD_ALT = 0x0001;
        public const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
        public const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x004;
        public const int MOD_NOREPEAT = 0x400;
        public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        public const int DSIX = 0x36;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool r = RegisterHotKey(Handle, 1, MOD_ALT, DSIX);

            if (!r)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("can't do..");
                return;
            }

            Message msg = new Message();

            while (GetMessage(ref msg,IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("do work..");
                }
            }


        }
    }


    public class Message
    {
        public int message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

when the target is pressed, I get the following error:

```
Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
```

what's is this? how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Message class doesn't have enough members so GetMessage() corrupts the garbage collected heap.  Override WndProc() instead.  Search "setvisiblecore" to find out how to keep the window invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doomed to failure.  If you write your own message loop it will stop WinForms receiving any messages.

Instead, override the [PreProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.preprocessmessage.aspx) or [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) functions.